# Preserving nulls in LINQ inner joins

Tags: c#, linq, null, c#-8.0

This code does an inner join on `special` and `things` then produces the indices into `things` of the corresponding matches:

```
object[] special = {      'b',    null, 5.0f,      "notme" };
object[] things  = { "a", 'b', 3, null, 5.0f, 6.0          };

var specialThingIndices = from tn in things.Select((t,n) => (t,n)) 
                          join s in special on tn.t equals s
                          select tn.n;

foreach (var n in specialThingIndices)
    Console.WriteLine($"[{n}] = {Convert.ToString(things[n])}, {things[n] is null}");
```

It outputs:

```
[1] = b, False
[4] = 5, False
```

However, `null` appears in both arrays and I do not want to skip that. So what I *want* it to output is:

```
[1] = b, False
[3] = , True
[4] = 5, False
```

Why isn't it seeing the `null`s and how can I make it keep them?

I tried hand-wavily applying `DefaultIfEmpty()` in various places with no success. I also tried replacing `equals` with `==` but I guess that's not valid syntax. I couldn't think of anything else.

Runnable example is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LHPita).

Comment: `from s in special where Equals(tn.t,  s)`

Comment: @GertArnold [It works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPplvj) (*and* makes sense to me). Thanks!!!

Comment: It's confusing to me that the [docs for `equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#the-equals-operator) don't mention that behavior. It's also odd that it says it "it differs from the == operator in *one* important way" (emphasis mine) and then identifies that one way as the scope rule differences. There's definitely a few other "important" differences... 

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/24528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a default value if null, for example the `"<null>"` string.

```
...
object[] special = { 'b', null, 5.0f, "notme" };
object[] things = { "a", 'b', 3, null, 5.0f, 6.0 };

var specialThingIndices = from tn in things.Select(x => x ?? "<null>").Select((t, n) => (t, n))
                          join s in special.Select(x => x ?? "<null>") on tn.t equals s
                          select tn.n;

foreach (var n in specialThingIndices)
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{n}] = {Convert.ToString(things[n])}, {things[n] is null}");
...
```

**Edit**
Another solution using `Where` instead of `join`.

```
...
object[] special = { 'b', null, 5.0f, "notme" };
object[] things = { "a", 'b', 3, null, 5.0f, 6.0 };

var specialThingIndices = from tn in things.Select((t, n) => (t, n))
                          where special.Any(s => Equals(s, tn.t))
                          select tn.n;

foreach (var n in specialThingIndices)
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{n}] = {Convert.ToString(things[n])}, {things[n] is null}");
...
```